# How to copy values of a field in Array of object into another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I want to ask if there is a better solution to what I used in order to obtain this:

Input

```
  arr = [
     {value:1, role:""},
     {value:2, role:""},
     {value:4, role:""},
     {value:5, role:""}
  ];
```

Output

```
  outputArr = [1, 2, 4, 5];
```

My solution, so far, is:

```
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    outputArr.push(arr[i].value);
  }
```

but is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What does 'better' mean for you. The answers point to `.map`, which is another option, but the `for` loop is faster.

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky - You'd want to benchmark it. I wouldn't be surprised if `map` were every bit as fast as the loop above, on any decent JavaScript engine. :-)

Comment: Benchmark results -> https://hackernoon.com/javascript-performance-test-for-vs-for-each-vs-map-reduce-filter-find-32c1113f19d7, modern engines do strive to enhance the performance of those functions so we might see the time when it doesn't matter at all

Comment: You can see which is more faster loop or map. I have added an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead:

```js
let arr = [
     {value:1, role:""},
     {value:2, role:""},
     {value:4, role:""},
     {value:5, role:""}
  ];
  
let output = arr.map(el => el.value);

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Surely you didn't think such a basic question had gone unasked and unanswered all these years? :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
  let arr = [
     {value:1, role:""},
     {value:2, role:""},
     {value:4, role:""},
     {value:5, role:""}
  ];

  let outputArr = arr.map((e)=>e.value)

  console.log(outputArr)
```

Comment: Surely you didn't think such a basic question had gone unasked and unanswered all these years? :-)

Answer (score 1):

See this

```js
arr = [
     {value:1, role:""},
     {value:2, role:""},
     {value:4, role:""},
     {value:5, role:""}
  ];
var d=arr.map((x)=>x.value)
console.log(d)
```

You can check which one is more faster

```js
arr = [
     {value:1, role:""},
     {value:2, role:""},
     {value:4, role:""},
     {value:5, role:""}
  ];

console.time('Using Loop');
var aOut=[];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   aOut.push(arr[i].value);
}
console.timeEnd('Using Loop')


console.time('Using Map');
var bOut = arr.map((e)=>e.value)
console.timeEnd('Using Map')
```

Comment: Everyone given the same answers

Comment: Surely you didn't think such a basic question had gone unasked and unanswered all these years? :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes agreed :)